# How do I make a rectangle from adjacent misaligned rectangles?

Tags: faces, looping

If I have a selection like the one below, is there a way to do some sort of loop edit that makes the outer selected edge a rectangle?
[image]

Kind of like this, but with a rectangle

[image]